# How to compare the Xml file containing list of regular Expression with another XML in java?

Tags: java, xml, regex

EX: 
I want to Compare this two file and filter out the common things...

1. Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0;) OR 1=1 --

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0;) AND 1=1 --

1. Mozilla/[0-9].0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0;) [A-Z] 1=1 --

Comment: What is your question exactly? Which comparative standard are you using?

Comment: I want to compare above mentioned two line which is in one xml with another XML containing the regular expression...

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Hello user3567643! Your question is very vague. Please try to explain your problem with more details and context so we are able to understand what you mean. Start at the beginning. And one step after another. 1. Your have some XML files. What files exactly. Give as an example. 2. You are talking about regular expressions. Are these regular expressions part of the XML? Or do you have to write some regular expressions to achieve something (what?)? This is very unclear. Be more specific. We cannot read your mind. Then try it yourself, write some code and show us your code.

Comment: Consider this first two set of data is in One XML file and other line in another XML... So I want compare this two file and print the uncommon things which is present in one file and not in other... I'm able to read the two file now I want to filter out? Using regular expression can I do??? HOw?? Coz Mozilla/4.0 ---- AND/OR are common things.. So I thought of using regular expression... So that I don't need to write all things in one of the XML... I'm thinking of useing like this... for EX: Mozilla/[0-9].0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0;) [A-Z] 1=1 -- Help me in solving this..